# Determine which MKPinAnnotationView was selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mapkit

I place some custom MKPinAnnotationView on the map, with different information about landmarks (name, description, image, accessory button). When a user click and open one of the pins, and then click the accessory button inside it, I want to know which of the pins the user have clicked so I can load a viewcontroller with more detailed information.

I found these methods:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   
{
}
```

... but how do I know which pin was selected? I would like to do something like:

```
   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   
    {
        //Example
        if ([view.description isEqualToString: @"Golden Gate"])
        {
             //Load golden gate information in a new viewcontroller
        }
    }
```

...but view.description won't give me the right information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're storing the name/description in the `title`/`subtitle` of your `MKAnnotationView` you can access these informations just by accessing to the [`annotation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/annotation) property of the `MKAnnotationView`:

```
if ([view.annotation.title isEqualToString: @"Golden Gate"])
   {
         //Load golden gate information in a new viewcontroller
   }
```