# MKAnnotation random order in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a table view with an ordered list of objects, ordered by distance between me and the object. I need to show annotations in a map to show to the user the position of the objects but i need to show in the same order than table´s order because then i need to get with one has been pressed to show info of each object.

The problem is that when I put the annotations in the map each time I put them the tag number of the annotation is different. Is like the map added the annotations in a random order.

I have an annotations array and then I add that array to the map:

```
    MKPointAnnotation* tallerAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [tallerAnnotation setCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([taller getLatitudTaller],       [taller getLongitudTaller])];
    [tallerAnnotation setTitle:[taller getNombre]];
    [tallerAnnotation setSubtitle:[taller getDomicilio]];
    [annotations addObject:tallerAnnotation];
```

And then add the array to the map:

```
    [mapa addAnnotations:annotations];
```

Here is the code where I custom the annotation:

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapa viewForAnnotation: (id <MKAnnotation>) annotation_ {

    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapa dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"YourPinId"];
    if (pin == nil) {
    pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation_ reuseIdentifier: @"YourPinId"];


    }
    else {
    pin.annotation = annotation_;
    }
    if ([[annotation_ title]isEqualToString:@"Tu posición"])
    pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    else
    {
    [pin setCanShowCallout:YES];
    pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getInfoTalleres:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [rightButton setTag:posicionActualTaller]; 
    pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    UILabel *l1=[[UILabel alloc] init];
    l1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 5, 50, 15);
    l1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    l1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    l1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(10.0)];
    l1.text=[[[mainDelegate getTalleres]objectAtIndex: posicionActualTaller]getDistancia];
    posicionActualTaller +=1;
    UIView *leftCAV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,15)];
    [leftCAV  addSubview : l1];
    pin.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftCAV;
    }


    pin.animatesDrop = YES;
    return pin;
    }
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
    {
    NSLog(@"Tag del taller = %i",[control tag]);
    [mainDelegate setTallerActual:[[mainDelegate getTalleres]objectAtIndex:[control tag]]];
    [self detalleTaller];
    }
```

[control tag] has differents values each time I enter into map view so that way it´s impossible do something like [objects objectAtIndex:[control tag]];

Please I need help.

Thanks in advance.

**Ok finally I have found a solution.**

When I create the

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getInfoTalleres:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

for the annotation I assign the annotation title to the button this way:

```
[rightButton setTitle:[annotation_ subtitle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then:

```
-(void)getInfoTalleres:(UIButton* )sender
{   
for (int i = 0; i < [[mainDelegate getTalleres]count]; i++)
{
    if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:[[[mainDelegate getTalleres]objectAtIndex:i]getDomicilio]])
    {
        [mainDelegate setTallerActual:[[mainDelegate getTalleres]objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self detalleTaller];
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Hope somebody can use this solution.

Thanks a lot Cocoa.

Regards.

Comment: still i can't understand your problem :( please explain

Comment: When I do this:

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
    {
    NSLog(@"Tag del taller = %i",[control tag]);
    [mainDelegate setTallerActual:[[mainDelegate getTalleres]objectAtIndex:[control tag]]];
    [self detalleTaller];
    }

[sender tag] has a different value every time I enter into the map view, so that way it´s impossible to do something like [objects objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];

Comment: you can access title or subtitle in callOutAccesory. with title you can get your object.

Comment: [control title] is not working for me, I only can get the tag of the control, that´s because I need that the tag of the control be the same all the time and does not change every time I enter into MapView

Answer (score 0):

Check the Answer here it access title property [Determine which MKPinAnnotationView was selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739335/determine-which-mkpinannotationview-was-selected) and the tutorial http://www.scribd.com/doc/91629556/192/The-MKAnnotationView-class

let me know if you still not find answer

Comment: Hi Cocoa.

I have read the links and this could be a solution if I only had one or two annotations. The problem is that I don´t know how many annotations have because I receive the objects from data base so I think that do something like this:

if ([view.annotation.title isEqualToString: @"Golden Gate"])
   {
         //Load golden gate information in a new viewcontroller
   }

is not useful for me, but thanks anyway!!

Comment: you can compare with your array in for loop if you get current title then you can easily compare with all array for(int i =0; i<array.count;i++){ if ([view.annotation.title isEqualToString: [array objectAtIndex:i]]) { //Load golden gate information in a new viewcontroller }}